# how to remove chart completely in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

I have multiple charts in my home page and I have a search box to filter them by chart name.

when I filter particular chart I can delete that chart while it's begin filtered and it disappear from UI but some reason the chart that I just deleted still appear in the home page with the rest of the other charts when I unfiltered/removed all the text in the search box.

It got deleted in the backend but the deleted chart is still appearing in the front end. Also for some reason I can still search it again the one that I just deleted but this time I can not delete it again since it throw 404.

It only disappear completely when I refresh the browser. Any suggestion on how I can make the chart to disappear even after I unfiltered in the search box.

HTML

```
//Imported this component to display a list of chart
<ng-container *ngFor="let chart of charts">
   <mc-chart-list [chart]="chart" [wsType]="workspace.type" (removeFromList)="onRemoveFromList($event)"></mc-chart-list>
</ng-container>

//I use this searchbar to filter by the name of the chart
 <input class="input" matInput name="query" [formControl]="query" placeholder="Filter Workspace">
```

TS

```
@Input() chart: Chart;
workspace: Workspace;
private death$: Subject<void> = new Subject();
query: FormControl = new FormControl();
charts: Chart[] = [];
searchText: string;


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(takeUntil(this.death$)).subscribe((paramMap) => {
      const guid = paramMap.get('guid');

      if (guid) {
        this.workspaceService.getWorkspace(guid, this.isPublished).subscribe(ws => {
          this.workspace = ws;
        }, () => this.loading = false);
      }
    })

//For search bar
    this.query.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.death$))
      .subscribe((value: string) => {
        this.search(value);
      });
}
search(searchText: string){
    // reset
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
    if (!searchText || searchText.length == 0) {
      this.charts = this.workspace.charts;
    }
    // search
    else {
      this.charts = this.charts.filter(chart => chart.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) >= 0);
    }
  }

onRemoveFromList(id: number) {
    const index = this.charts.findIndex(e => e.id === id);
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.charts.splice(index, 1);
}
```

I can do this.ngOnIt() inside the search funtion but I don't think that will be best way to do it so I'll be really appreciated if someone can help me fix this.

Comment: what about using a flag to check if it is filtered yet or not? and have you ever tried angular changedetector ?

Comment: Hi Ali, no I have not use both so by anychance can you help me with that?. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your workspace.charts have the all the charts.you are assigning value for `charts` from `workspace.charts`.In your `onRemoveFromList` function you only remove it from `chart`.but `workspace.charts` still have that removed value.then whenever you reset the search the removed values going in to the `charts` that is why you see those removed charts.

Solution: in your `onRemoveFromList` remove the chart from `workspace.charts` too.

> ```
>   onRemoveFromList(id: number) {
>     const index = this.charts.findIndex(e => e.id === id);
>     if (index >= 0) {
>       this.charts.splice(index, 1);
>       this.workspace.charts = this.workspace.charts.filter(e => e.id !== id);
>     }
> ```

Comment: It work after setting e.id !== id instead. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciated it.

Comment: yeah my bad..it must be id !== id.ill edit the post